# How to find list that represents average of two lists in python

Tags: python, list, average

I have two lists, for example:

```
A = [ 2, 4, 1 ]
B = [ 4, 0, 3 ]
```

I want to find `average list` with the fastest way as:

```
average list = [ 3, 2, 2]
```

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, try: `[(g + h) / 2 for g, h in zip(A, B)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 arrays must be equal length

```
res = []
for i in range(len(A)):
  res.append((A[i] + B[i]) / 2)
return res
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

you can use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) in combination with the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to achieve that:

```
 itertools.starmap(function, iterable)¶
```

> Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments obtained from the iterable. Used instead of map() when argument parameters are already grouped in tuples from a single iterable (the data has been “pre-zipped”).

this method works only on 2 lists:

```
from itertools import starmap
average_list = starmap(lambda (x,y):(x+y)/2,zip(list_1,list_2))
```

if you want to take also the rest of the lists and replace the missing elements by `0`, you have to use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead of `zip`:

```
from itertools import starmap,zip_longest
average_list = starmap(lambda (x,y):(x+y)/2,
                       zip_longest(list_1,list_2,fillvalue=0))
```

### Generalization

this can be expanded even further making a function that takes any list of any lenght:

```
def average(*x):
    return sum(x)/len(x)
def averagelist(*lists,fillvalue = None):
    if fillvalue is not None:
         return starmap(average,
                        zip_longest(*lists,fillvalue = fillvalue))
    return starmap(average,zip(*lists))
```

### Output

```
>>> A = [ 2, 4, 1 ]
>>> B = [ 4, 0, 3 ]
>>> list(averagelist(A,B))
[3.0, 2.0, 2.0]
```

### TL;DR

basically this can be achieved using the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), specifically the [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) and the [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) if you want to include also missing elements from lists. Here is the code with only 2 lists:

```
average_list = starmap(lambda (x,y):(x+y)/2,
                       zip_longest(list_1,list_2,fillvalue=0))
```

and here is the code generalized:

```
def average(*x):
    return sum(x)/len(x)
def averagelist(*lists,fillvalue = None):
    if fillvalue is not None:
         return starmap(average,
                        zip_longest(*lists,fillvalue = fillvalue))
    return starmap(average,zip(*lists))
```

### Notes

- the starmap function returns an iterator.

if you want to visualize it, you have to convert it to a list or tuple:

```
>>> print(starmap_object)
<itertools.starmap object at 0x000002D89AB11D80>
>>> print(list(starmap_object))
["example1","example2","example3"]
```

- in my example, the lists can be of different sizes.

The `zip` function altho will take the minimum lenght:

```
>>> list1 = [1,3,5,7]
>>> list2 = [2,4,6,8,9,10,11]
>>> pprint(list(zip(list1,list2)))
[[1,3,5,7],
 [2,4,6,8]]
```

### Useful links

- [`starmap` official wiki](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)
- [`zip` builtin function wiki](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`zip_longest` official wiki](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)
- [`itertools` module wiki](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)